# Read image stored as blob, directly into byte[] using springdata

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, blob, spring-data

I have an image stored in an Oracle database and I'm using spring data to retrieve the image.

```
@Query("SELECT c.binaryContent from ContentEntity c join c.ParentContentEntities pce where pce.SpecificEntity.id = :id and pce.contentType.id = 11")
byte [] getImageBinaryContent(@Param("id") Long id);


@Lob
@Column(name = "BINARY_CONTENT")
private byte [] binaryContent;


byte[] testImageArray = serviceLayer.getImageBinaryContent(id) RETURNS NULL
```

Tested individually this query works.  It finds content but when the call is made to getImageBinaryContent passing in an id, I get nothing back, just null result.  If I change the return type to blob, I successfully get a blob back.

Why can't I read a blob into a byte array directly?  My searches have shown examples of getting the blob returned, and then converting the blob with an inputstream into a byte array, but it seems like I should just be able to do this directly.

Comment: You can't just cast to incompatible types. A `byte[]` is different than a `Blob`.

Comment: It would be nice if there was some way to do this, as with spring data all queries are done in interfaces. If you want to return a byte array, or a stream, you will have to make a custom repository for every repo that has binary data. Returning a BLOB out of your data/repository layer is a bit of scope creep in my opinion. Are there "converters" that can be registered or something that could be used to handle this? The alternative of custom implementation to hook to a utility conversion method is not DRY